# java tomcat application variables

Tags: java, configuration, java-8, war, tomcat8

I'm quite new to full stack java web app developement. I developed an app which deals with **files uploads** by the user to the server. My question is:
How to set, particularly **the server-side storage path**?

To be more exhaustive, I developed my project as a *Java Web project in Netbeans (no Maven)*. I deployed the `.war`file on the remote server and everything works fine, but, as I developed the app locally, I have a storage path set to `c:\...`, and I want it more like `/opt/tomcat8/...`

So, as the `.war` way is simple to operate, but also "blackboxed", how should I do ? Is that possible to specify parameters in an external file, for example ?

Comment: What library are you using for file uploading?

Comment: I just send it in the request, as a `Part` (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/Part.html)

Comment: If you are using the `Part` (servlet 3.0), the directory where files will be stored is specified by "location" attribute of "@MultipartConfig".

This page shows an upload servlet example:
http://www.journaldev.com/2122/servlet-3-file-upload-multipartconfig-part

Do you want to dynamically change the "location" attribute?

Comment: For now I set the path in `web.xml`. My question, though perhaps not relevant, is : can I combine a way to generate a `.war` file which looks at an external conf file, so that my `.war` file is portable on different servers and the application is easily configured.... ?

Comment: If you don't want to set the directory path by a file in your war file, it might be a good idea to set a Java option (in catalina.sh and catalina.bat) and get it in your upload servlet.